# print variable to end of the file using sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I wanted to print a variable(`var="phani"`) to the end of a text file (`2.txt`) using `sed`.

This is my work so far:

```
$ var="phani";echo sed -e "$a$var" -i 2.txt
```

But the error i am getting is :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't get an error, but I also get no "action" .. ie nothing happens. What's the value of `$a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you're using dbl-quotes (to allow for var expansion), you have to escape the first $ so the shell doesn't try to evaluate '$a', this works for me ..

```
 sed "\$a$(var)" file
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to protect the `$a` from shell expansion:

```
var="phani";echo sed -e '$a'"$var" -i 2.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason that `echo "$var" >> 2.txt` isn't sufficient? Using `sed` for this is making an easy task more difficult than it needs to be...